# Installing ubuntu on a new empty internal hard drive

Tags: boot, system-installation, bios

Recently my old hard drive died - it wouldn't let me boot ubuntu at all and all I could do was to get a new one.

I created a bootable flash drive with the newest ubuntu version on it. I put the flash drive in and hit the power button and all I got was the boot menu with just one option `ubuntu`, which doesn't work as there is nothing on the hard drive. I tried to open BIOS using F12 but all I ever get is the boot menu. And I can do nothing! I have tried all kinds of combinations, like <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>DEL</kbd>, <kbd>ESC</kbd>, <kbd>STRG</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>DEL</kbd> but nothing works. I cant get into BIOS to change to "boot from flashdrive".

[image]

Comment: You need to press whatever key your system uses, that tells your system what device to boot (where you can tell it the thumb-drive you wrote your Ubuntu install media to).  I've used systems today that used F9, and others that required F12. I have systems here that require different keys to those I mentioned - ie. the key pressed is device specific (whatever the firmware on the device uses).

Answer (score 0):

Some HP systems use F10 to enter boot.  If you see the boot screen logo, it may be too late.  Start pressing even before you see the boot logo.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions. But I have tried this already. I press the power button and F12 as my system asks me to. But all I get is this screen. I also tried power button and F2. Same result. I can hear the "Beep" but then I get this screnn.